# Generic method in Java, syntax

Tags: java, generics

What is happening in line 6? `<C extends Cat>` is the return type of useMe, right? What does `<? super Dog>` do?

```
2. class Animal { }
3. class Dog extends Animal { }
4. class Cat extends Animal { }
5. public class Mixer<A extends Animal> {
6. public <C extends Cat> Mixer<? super Dog> useMe(A a, C c) {
7. //Some code
8. } }
```

Comment: I think useMe is your method.  
if this is the case then you are wrong at  <C extends Cat> Mixer<? super Dog>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<C extends Cat>` specifies that `useMe` has one generic parameter, `C`, which must extend `Cat`.

Its return type is `Mixer<? super Dog>`.  The `?` denotes a [**wildcard**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me how to use more than one generic parameters here? Separating by comma is not working. (like <C extends Cat>, <D extends Dog>)

Answer (score 3):

No, the return type is `Mixer<? super Dog>`, and the method itself is a generic method which uses a generic parameter `C`, which can any class that extends `Cat`, and is used as a parameter `C c`

Answer (score 3):

The first generic parameter specification `<C extends Cat>` makes `useMe` a generic method parametrized with parameter `C` which derives from `Cat` or is `Cat` itself.

The second generic parameter specification `<? super Dog>` refers to the method's return type which is a parametrized `Mixer` where the sole generic parameter is a super class of `Dog` or `Dog` class itself.

Thus, line 6 means: `useMe` is a generic method parametrized with `C` deriving from `Cat` (or being `Cat` itself). The method takes two arguments of types `A` and `C` and returns type `Mixer` parametrized with a super-type of `Dog` (possibly `Dog` itself).

Answer (score 2):

`<C extends Cat>` is NOT the return type. `Mixer<? super Dog>` is.
The former is only specified to specify the type of c.